# Replace entry in String Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `String Array` with multiple entries in it. I want to transcribe this `String Array` into another one, replacing specific entries with a digit (`k` in this case).
What I've tried so far:

```
public void replace(String[] eqh, char var, int maxX){
String[] holder = new String[eqh.length];
    String  comp = "";
    for (int k = -maxX/2; k <= maxX/2; k++){
        for (int i = 0; i< eqh.length; i++){
            if (eqh[i].equals(var)){
                holder[i] = ""+k; 
            } else {
                holder[i] = eqh[i];
            } 
            comp = Arrays.toString(holder);
            System.out.println("comp: "+comp);
        } 
/// some stuff with comp here
}
```

Unfourtunatley this is not working, the return for `comp` is exactly the same as the input from `eqh`.

Comment: You're changing `holder` (a variable that exists only in `replace`'s scope), I don't see how `eqh` is affected.

Comment: Some debugging should help you figure out

Comment: You are comparing strings with chars in eqh[i].equals(var) (it will always return false). If you want to check whether first char is equals to var, do eqh[i].charAt(0) == var

Comment: eqh shouldnt be affected, because ill have to transcribe it multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings with chars in `eqh[i].equals(var)` (it will always return false). If you want to check whether first char is equals to var, do `eqh[i].charAt(0) == var`

Also, it is not a good practice to convert integers to strings doing `""+k`. Use `Integer.toString(k)` or `String.valueOf(k)`.

Comment: You are welcome. Also check my advice about integers conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check if a `String` is equals to a `char`, the result of this test will always be false.

You can use `eqh[i].indexOf(var) >= 0` to test if a String contains a char.